# Let Alphabet have only one unary function of symbol f. Prove that every term must have 3K+1 symbols for some k≥0.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I believe in order to solve this question, I have to perform induction on the complexity of terms. But I'm not sure how to begin.

Comment: I recommend repeating your question statement inside the actual question itself, rather than only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every term has shape $f(t)$ for some term $t$. So we have added $3$ symbols to the symbols in $t$, namely $f$, $($ and $)$.

Comment: and how does that increase by 3t+ 1 every time a new term is added? t being the number of terms.

Comment: The basic terms (variable symbols and constant symbols, if any) have length $1$. If $t$ has length $3k+1$, then $f(t)$ has length $3k+1+3$, which is $3(k+1)+1$, so of the right shape.

Comment: @user165950 The "(" and ")" count as symbols so every time you add another f() to your term that is another 3 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This is hilarious, im almost positive im in the same class as you.
Read Tourlakis 4.1.6 (3), it makes it as clear as possible. Use induction on complexity of terms to prove.